# Unable to open Bliss OS after making changes in boot code

Tags: shell, grub, boot-loader, android, solus

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /bliss-x86-11.13/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/bliss-x86-11.13
initrd /bliss-x86-11.13/initrd.img}
```

After making the changes in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`. I was able to visit Bliss OS but, it was automatically downloading img

[image]

[image]

While I have system.img although when I executed updated grub then, reboot my laptop again I saw it was automatically installing again. For this reason I was unable to open Bliss OS. It stuck while showing animation...

[image]

While Bliss OS animation shows something else...! This is error after open the OS from boot. I think the error keep occurs cause, when I execute `sudo update-grub` I get error.

> Generating grub configuration file ...
> WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
> Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1
> done

Here how it(animation) actually looks like

[image]

Here how turned on Bliss OS

[image]

From that source code I am unable to get system.img that's why it was downloading I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`androidboot.hardware=generic_x86` this might be the culprit

```
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,2)'
linux /bliss-x86-11.13/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86_64 acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/bliss-x86-11.13
initrd /bliss-x86-11.13/initrd.img}
```